# Unable to iterate an array in a PHP foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

My request **PHP** file elaborates some **Ajax** **POST** `data`:

**POST data**

```
data[0][id]:359
data[0][position]:1
data[1][id]:321
data[1][position]:2
data[2][id]:354
data[2][position]:3
```

**Request.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['data'])) {
    if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && isset($_SESSION['password'])) {

        $verify = $loggedIn->verify();

        if($verify['username']) {
            $Profile = new Profile();
            $Profile->db = $db;
            //Call my function
            $messages = $Profile->setOrder($_POST['data']);     

        }
    }
}
```

**Profile.php**

```
function setOrder($post) {
    var_dump($post);

    foreach($post as $item)
    {
        return "Area ID ".$item["id"]." and person located ".$item["position"]."<br />";
    }
}
```

My function returns nothing and the dump of `$post` is as below

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "359"
    ["position"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "321"
    ["position"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "354"
    ["position"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
}
```

Inside my function I can `dump` correctly something like `var_dump($post[0]["id"]);` so why my `foreach` loop is empty?

Comment: Try to `var_dump($item);` inside the loop. Maybe it will reveal something.

Comment: You're not actually telling your `foreach()` to output anything, merely `return` - which will assign that string to `$messages = $Profile->setOrder($_POST['data']);` and terminate the loop.

Comment: you don't loop because `return` breaks the loop

Comment: I missed the `return`. Do you want to `echo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are using `return` inside loop. It will terminate the loop after first iteration. You need to do something like this.

```
$return = null;
foreach($data as $item)
{
    $return .= "Area ID ".$item["id"]." and person located ".$item["position"]."<br />";
}
return $return;
```